# How can I play video by touching the button on the video thumnail of the video in tableviewcell?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiimageview, uibutton

I have a table view in which if each cell is touched a video plays.
Each cell have image of the video cell.imageView.image. And on the image I have a button (UIButton) with play symbol.

If I touch the play button the corresponding video should be played same like the when cell is touched.

I have a selector for the play button. But how can I know that particular row is selected by touching the play button. How can I play the video when I touched the button ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a selector for the play button. But how can I know that
>   particular row is selected by touching the play button

You can get the item selected from the table by indexPath.row.

Whereas for the sond quest how to play the video I m not sure...